# Same message repeating 3 times

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have code below that takes the first column and prints it in a google doc based on the date. Unfortunately, this repeats and prints the row three times.

```js
function saveAsDOC() {
  var fileName = "Announcements Test File";
  var doc = DocumentApp.create(fileName);

  // Get the range in the spreadsheet
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange();
  try {
    var data = ws.getValues();

    // Announcements loop
    if (data.length > 1) { // Make sure data is longer than one character
      for (var row = 1; row < data.length; row++) {
        if(new Date(data[row][2]) <= new Date()) { // Check the date
          for (var col = 1; col < data[row].length; col++) {
            if(data[row][col]!=""){ // Make sure the data is not empty
              doc.appendParagraph(data[row][1]); // Append announcement
              doc.appendParagraph("") // Line break between announcements
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }

  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
  }
}
```

The source data is in a Google spreadsheet, with three columns "Announcement", "Start date" and "End date". I want to compile a list of announcements for "today" (i.e. today's date is between the start & end dates, inclusively).

```
                A                     B             C
1 | Announcement               | Start date  | End date    |
2 | You SHOULD see this.       | 1 Jan 2015  | 31 Dec 2015 |
3 | You SHOULD NOT see this.   | 1 Jan 2015  | 1 Jan 2015  |
4 | You SHOULD ALSO see this.  | 1 Jan 2015  | 31 Dec 2015 |
5 | You SHOULD NOT see this.   | 31 Dec 2015 | 31 Dec 2015 |
```

Here is an example of my output:
[image: output]

My code is skipping the announcements that should not bee seen, that's good. But it's printing the expected announcements multiple times. How can I fix that?

Comment: Your question isn't clear, you need to [edit] in some more info, and reduce the code to a [mcve]. What does your data look like? (An example that produces your problem would help.) The creation of a doc is irrelevant to the problem you're facing, take it out, and use a simpler way to track execution of the inner loop, like a log. Likewise, no need for any UI part (`toast`). If you make the _core_ problem easily reproducible, you'll get better answers... and possibly figure it out yourself!

Comment: I've updated my post. I'm clear on how to post questions, as I unfortunately do it all the time and get no answers.

Comment: Try this. Pick any row in your spreadsheet that has an announcement that currently shows up 3 times in your document. Add another cell at the end of the row, with anything in it. Then run the script. You should see 4 copies of that announcement now.

Comment: I've done so and it prints 4 copies. I'm assuming the row `for (var row = 1; row < data.length; row++) {` has something to do with it?

Comment: Part, yes - that loops over all cells in the row. Combined with the comparison that checks whether a cell is empty, you'll end up printing _something_ for every non-empty cell. And that something is always the _same thing_ because you append `data[row][1]`.

Comment: That was the way I was told to select the first column, is there a workaround?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88129/discussion-between-mogsdad-and-techteej).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a minimal version of your code that demonstrates the problem, with comments added explaining what's happening:

```
function announcements() {
  // Get the range in the spreadsheet
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange();
  var data = ws.getValues();
  var results = [];

  if (data.length > 1) {                                    // Make sure data is longer than one ROW (not character)
    for (var row = 1; row < data.length; row++) {           // Skips first row, then loop over the rest is that what you want?
      if(new Date(data[row][2]) <= new Date()) {            // Check the date, [2] is the third column.
        for (var col = 1; col < data[row].length; col++) {  // Loop over all columns except the first one
          if(data[row][col]!=""){                           // Make sure the data is not empty
            results.push(data[row][1]);                     // Append [row][1]; **** Same value
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  Logger.log( JSON.stringify( results ) );
}
```

You've got a few possible problems here:

- `if (data.length > 1)` checks that you have more than one *row* of data, which mismatches your comment. Make sure it's what you want to do.
- `for (var row = 1; etc.` loops over all rows, but skips the first row. Maybe that's what you want, but a common problem the folks run into is that the spreadsheet rows (and columns) are numbered starting at 1 when you use Google's Spreadsheet methods, but from 0 in JavaScript arrays. The content of `data` is a JavaScript array, so it starts from 0.(Discussed in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88129/discussion-between-mogsdad-and-techteej), this was understood, so no problem there.)
- `if(new Date(data[row][2]) <= new Date())` only checks if the "End date" is a date up to an including today. You also need to check the "Start date". (Discussed in chat.)
- `for (var col = 1; col < data[row].length; col++)` loops over all the columns (in each row). Then `if(data[row][col]!="")` checks if that cell is non-blank, and `results.push(data[row][1])` appends the "announcement". **This is why you're seeing repeated announcements.** According to your problem statement, there is no need to loop across the row, you just want to check whether there is an announcement for each row.

#### Updated code

```
function announcements() {
  // Get the range in the spreadsheet
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange();
  var data = ws.getValues();
  
  var announcementCol = 1,    // "constants" for column numbers
      dateCol = 2;
  var results = [];           // Array to hold announcements for today

  if (data.length > 1) {
    // Loop over rows that contain announcements
    for (var row = 1; row < data.length; row++) {
      // Check that today is a date that the announcement should be included.
      if(new Date(data[row][1]) <= new Date() && new Date(data[row][2]) >= new Date() ) {
        // Is there an announcement in this row?
        if(data[row][announcementCol]!=""){
          // Add this announcement to results
          results.push(data[row][announcementCol]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Show results in log
  Logger.log( JSON.stringify( results ) );
}
```